# Divide two timespans by eachother in Python/dateutil

Tags: python, python-dateutil

please consider this problem:

I have a date in the past from where I start adding periods. When adding these periods results in a date greater than today, I want to stop, and check what the last date is.

This is a functionality for calculating debit dates in a membership. A member joins, say, 2007-01-31. He is debited every month. Let's say today is 2013-03-29 (it actually is atm). So I need to start counting months since 2007-01-31 and when I get past today's date, I need to stop. I can then see that the next debit date is 2013-03-31.

I am using the dateutil library to implement this, adding relativedelta's in a while loop until I surpass the current date. (I know it's probably not the best way, but I'm still quite new at Python and this is a proof-of-concept). The problem is that when I add a month to 2007-01-31, the next date is 2007-02-28, which is correct. But the next iteration the date is 2007-03-28, because dateutil doesn't recognize the 28th as the last day of the month to keep it intact and iterate to the last day of march. Ofcourse, that's a perfectly valid implementation. I then experimented with dateutils rrule object, but it has the same principles. It outputs a list of dates, but it simply skips the months that don't have enough days.

```
period = rrule(MONTHLY, interval=1, dtstart=datetime.date(2012, 5, 31), until=datetime.date(2013, 3, 29))
print(list(period))
```

Then I thought of a different approach:

If I could count the number of periods in the timespan between 2007-01-31 and 2013-03-29, I can add those number of periods to the startdate, and dateutil would return the right date.
The problem there is that the period isn't always one month. It can also be four weeks, a quarter or a year, for example.

I couldn't find a way to take a relativedelta and divide it with another relativedelta, to get a number of times the latter goes in the first.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Is there, for example, a library that can do this (divide timespans by each other, and output the result in a given timeblock, like months or weeks)? Is there perhaps a datediff function that accepts a period as an input (I know for example [in vbscript you can get the difference between two dates in whatever period you want](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_datediff.asp), be it weeks, months, days, whatever). Is there perhaps a totally different solution?

For completeness, I will include the code, but I think the text explains it all already:

```
def calculate(self, testdate=datetime.date.today()):
    self._testdate = testdate


    while self.next < self._testdate:
        self.next += self._ddinterval
    self.previous = self.next - self._ddinterval
    return self.next
```

Thanks,

Erik

**edit**: I now have a solution that does what it's supposed to, but it's hardly Pythonic, elegant or speedy. So the question remains the same, if anyone can come up with a better solution, please do. Here's what I came up with:

```
def calculate(self, testdate=datetime.date.today()):
    self._testdate = testdate

    start = self.next
    count = 0
    while self.next < self._testdate:
        count += 1
        self.next = start + (count * self._ddinterval)
    self.previous = self.next - self._ddinterval
    return self.next
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem using another date handling module. My solution with it for periods measured in months was simply to compare the day of the month of the result after adding the interval to that of the starting date and adjust it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks Martineau, that would work, but only for months, not for adding periods of 4 weeks, for example. I've found quite a few examples for adding just months.

Comment: IMO Adding 4 weeks (or anything where no. of days in a span are fixed) is easy. For  4 weeks you will always add 28 days to your time. So even something like `old_datetime + timedelta(days=28)` will work. For months and quarters it is not so easy beacuse different months have different number of days.

Comment: Thanks for your input, RedBaron. I thought about making that distinction. However, the _ddinterval property is a relativedelta object, and I couldn't find a way to check such an object for the period. (No way to find out if it contains weeks, days, years, or a combination). If I could convert a relativedelta object to, say "weeks" that would make things a lot easier.

Comment: I haven't had much experience with `dateutil`, so can't comment about that. How do you set `_ddinterval` BTW?

Comment: Well, the intervals are stored in a legacy database as a period (string) and a count (integer). The database was used in classic ASP, and it uses the vbscript conventions for storing timespans. "ww", 1 is one week. 3 "q" is three quarters. I wrote a helper function to convert these database values to a relativedelta.

Comment: Your edited solution is what I was about to suggest for the months part. Another way would be to ditch `dateutil` and define your own class that accepts spacings like `week 1` or `day 31` or `month 2` or `quarter 1` and write functions that calculate the new times. But it would be a bit like re-inventing the wheel

Comment: What happens if the starting date is 2010-03-31? We are now in April, so there is *no* 2013-04-31, only 2013-04-30.

Comment: Martijn: that's exactly the problem. In this case (a membership system) the next direct debit date should be 2013-04-30, the next one after that 2013-05-31. So if a member joins on any day of the month, except for the last day, it should just add months. When the date is the last day of the month, then the debits should be the last day of each month. The datutil function does this, but not when you do it in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the new value after adding your period as the starting point for the next loop, create an ever-increasing *delta* instead:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
start = datetime.date(2007, 1, 31)
period = relativedelta(months=1)

delta = period
while start + delta < today:
    delta += period

next = start + delta
```

This results in:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> start = datetime.date(2007, 1, 31)
>>> period = relativedelta(months=1)
>>> delta = period
>>> while start + delta < today:
...     delta += period
... 
>>> delta
relativedelta(years=+6, months=+3)
>>> start + delta
datetime.date(2013, 4, 30)
```

This works for any variable period lengths including quarters and years. For periods measured in exact weeks or days you can use a `timedelta()` object too, but this is a generic solution.

You cannot 'divide' time periods when using variable-width periods such as months and quarters. For time periods measured in whole days you can simply convert the difference between two dates to days (from the timedelta) and then get the modulus:

```
period = datetime.timedelta(days=28)  # 4 weeks
delta = today - start
remainder = delta.days % period.days
end = today + datetime.timedelta(days=remainder)
```

which gives:

```
>>> period = datetime.timedelta(days=28)  # 4 weeks
>>> delta = today - start
>>> remainder = delta.days % period.days
>>> today + datetime.timedelta(days=remainder)
datetime.date(2013, 4, 17)
```

Comment: I've added that downvote prior to your edit mentioning other periods. As mentioned in question, not only months could be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is the most elegant way of doing it. I will have to devise a way to separate "fixed" periods from "variable" ones, but I think that's feasible.

Comment: This is a very good solution to get the closest next month date, especially for recurring monthly tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If your delta is variable with respect to base time (i.e., 1 month can mean any of 28-31 days depending), then you're stuck with a loop.

If delta is a constant day count, however, you can sidestep iteration by converting to integers and doing a modulo operation.